# Getting datas from gridview for selected row?

Tags: asp.net

i'm new to asp.net. i'm doing one project. in that i've used one gridview and fetch datas from database using sqldatasource.
gridview code is

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="Library" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sl_No" HeaderText="Sl_No" SortExpression="Sl_No" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Author" 
            SortExpression="Author" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Publication" HeaderText="Publication" 
            SortExpression="Publication" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Available" HeaderText="Status" 
            SortExpression="Available" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Availability">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Available") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RIUserTaken" HeaderText="RIUserTaken" 
            SortExpression="RIUserTaken" Visible="False" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Taken By" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RIUserTaken", "{0}") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="SendRequest" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="False" 
                    onclick="SendRequest_Click" CommandName="SendRequestCmd" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Taken Date" InsertVisible="False" 
            ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TakenDate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" /> </asp:GridView>
```

code  is one of the column of the grid view. if i click on that button, i've to store that button contains rows all datas in string variable. like
string slno="";
slno=gridview1.cells[0].text; (i'm not sure it is correct or not)
plz anyone help me??

thanks in advance :)

Comment: so work flow is ,
when i click SendRequest Button it goes to sendrequest.aspx page. even have to get that clicked row datas which have to pass that sendrequest.aspx page.
is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

From msdn, you should check this.
[GridView.SelectedIndexChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;

// Display the company name from the selected row.
// In this example, the third column (index 2) contains
// the company name.
MessageLabel.Text = "You selected " + row.Cells[2].Text + ".";
}

void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{

// Get the currently selected row. Because the SelectedIndexChanging event
// occurs before the select operation in the GridView control, the
// SelectedRow property cannot be used. Instead, use the Rows collection
// and the NewSelectedIndex property of the e argument passed to this 
// event handler.
GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];

// You can cancel the select operation by using the Cancel
// property. For this example, if the user selects a customer with 
// the ID "ANATR", the select operation is canceled and an error message
// is displayed.
if (row.Cells[1].Text == "ANATR")
{

  e.Cancel = true;
  MessageLabel.Text = "You cannot select " + row.Cells[2].Text + ".";

}
}
```

Comment: ya. Its rite Mr.user829081. now i've to pass those selected row datas to another page that is sendrequest.aspx. how to pass.?? i've to display those datas on sendrequest page. how to do??
any way to this one?

Comment: In grid event you store your value in session. After that use response redirect to go sendrequest.aspx.
Finally in this page get this values from session.

Answer (score 0):

Do these things

Step 1. Wire up a RowCommand Evnt to your GridView
 Step 2. Inside that event at code-behind, do this

```
if(e.CommandName.Equals("SendRequestCmd"))
{
    var clickedRow = ((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    // now access the cells like this
    var clickedSLNo = clickedRow.cells[0].Text;
}
```

---

Update:

[`e.CommandSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.commandsource.aspx) definition

> A instance of the System.Object class that represents the source of the command.

---

[`IButtonControl.CommandArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.ibuttoncontrol.commandargument.aspx) definition

> A control that implements the IButtonControl interface must implement the CommandArgument property and the CommandName property to indicate the argument and command name that are propagated to the Command event.

Comment: wat is the different between e.CommandSource and e.CommandArgument??

Comment: k. thank u Mr.naveen :) can u say one more thing. i've added u r suggested code. it doesn't make error. i've to pass this ClickedSLNo value to sendrequest.aspx page to display. how to pass. i've tried
Session["slno"]=clickedSLNo.ToString();
but its not working...
is there any other way???

Comment: You can use querystring: `Response.Redirect(String.Format("sendrequest.aspx?slno={0}", clickedSLNo));`

Comment: k Mr.codingbiz. but i've to assign that data to one variable.
lke
string slno="";
slno=clickedSLNo; how to do?

Comment: Use an array to store your row cells's value, and put this array to session. Session has to work.

Comment: i think so. its empty. i did the below things,
Session["slno"]=ClickedSLNo;
Session["bookname"]=ClickedBook; this code in row_command()
in sendrequest.aspx page, i've coded
response.write("slno:{0}\nbookname:{1}",clickedSLNo,clickedBook);
this code result as
slno: bookname: